# How to create a sparse layer in Keras (i.e. not all neurons are connected to each other)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

In Keras if there are two dense layers in a neural network, then all neurons of first layer are connected to ALL neurons of second layer. Can I delete few connections from the dense layer based on certain criteria on weight, such that the resultant is a sparse layer in which all neurons in first layer are not connected to all neurons in second layer??

I tried to reduce the weights that were below threshold to zero. But this did not serve the purpose of deleting / removing the weight connections from the network because after I re-trained the network,, the weights that were forced to be zero regained some values due to gradient descent.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If the aim is to avoid overfitting, use dropout as suggested by Jonno_FTW below. Or do you want to reduce the number of variables that need to be learnt? In that case consider using convolutional layers and max pooling.

Comment: @Karl I want to delete specific weight connections between two layers. So, when I save the model network, it will require less space. Also, if I delete specific weight connections, then gradient will not be computed for them, thus saving time. Please let me know if this makes the question clear

Comment: Deleting individual weight connections will not help you particularly much. For one thing, how will you know which ones to delete? The whole point of a neural network is that it will itself learn which connections are the most important. The right way to do this is by using techniques that map the raw representation of the input data onto a more densely packed format with fewer parameters. That is exactly what convolutional layers (ideally in combination with max pooling) do

Comment: @Karl I would first train the neural network to know which weights are important. Then, to know which weight connections to delete (i.e. the Unimportant weights), I would compare the weights to a threshold value. And finally delete the weights that are below a threshold value (i.e. delete weights that are not important).

Comment: @AakashKumar I'm not sure this is going to give you the desired effect. There are other ways to improve the size of neural networks than manually deleting weights. If this method was effective and well known, then major libraries would provide utilities and layers to do this. What I suggest is that you iteratively reduce the number of nodes/layers and retrain. Repeat until you have acceptable performance/speed tradeoff.

Comment: @aks did you found a way on how to do this? I know that this is model pruning and I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding dropout? This will randomly reset some subset of weights in a layer to 0 when performing updates, and sounds like what you want.  This is one of many decent methods for combating overfitting.

https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/

Comment: Hello. I am sorry but dropuout is not solution to what I am looking for. I want to delete specific weight connections between two layers. So, when I save the model network, it will require less space. Also, if I delete specific weight connections, then gradient will not be computed for them, thus saving time. Please let me know if this makes the question clear. Now, these specific weight connections are NOT random. But they are selected based on weight values.

Comment: please check the above comment @Jonno_FTW